# Clean list of string containing escape sequence in python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm working on an OCR and the text extract from the image gets appended to a list that has a lot of escape sequences in it.

How can I clean a list of string like this

```
extracted = ["b'i)\\nSYRUP\\na\\n\\x0c'",
 "b'mi.\\n\\x0c'",
 "b'100\\n\\x0c'",
 "b'Te eT ran\\nSYRUP\\n\\x0c'",
 "b'tamol, Ambroxol k\\n\\x0c'",
 "b'Guaiphenesin\\n\\x0c'",
 "b'Syrup\\n\\x0c'",
 "b'ol HCl &\\n\\x0c'",
 "b'quantity.\\n\\x0c'"]
```

to this

```
cleaned= ["SYRUP",
 "mi",
 "100",
 "Te eT ran SYRUP",
 "tamol, Ambroxol k",
 "Guaiphenesin",
 "Syrup",
 "ol HCl &"
 "quantity"]
```

I tried replacing them but nothing works out and it goes back to how it was when extracted. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code that creates `extracted`? Something like `b'mi.\\n\\x0c'` is python syntax to denote binary data (note the **b** before the quote), but then all of it is again in between double quotes, that's very strange...

Answer (score 0):

For a start you could try:

```
for i, s in enumerate(extracted):
    extracted[i] =(s.replace("b'", '')
                   .replace("i)", '')
                   .replace('\\na', '')
                   .replace('\\n', '')
                   .replace("\\x0c'", '')
                   .replace('.', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be strings of bytecode string representation, which you can decode to utf-8. We use `literal_eval` from `ast` for safe evaluation.

This will get you most of the way there, oddities from OCR like `i)` you'll need to manually fix by replacing.

```
import ast

extracted = [
"b'i)\\nSYRUP\\na\\n\\x0c'",
"b'mi.\\n\\x0c'",
"b'100\\n\\x0c'",
"b'Te eT ran\\nSYRUP\\n\\x0c'",
"b'tamol, Ambroxol k\\n\\x0c'",
"b'Guaiphenesin\\n\\x0c'",
"b'Syrup\\n\\x0c'",
"b'ol HCl &\\n\\x0c'",
"b'quantity.\\n\\x0c'"]

def fix_string(s):
    eval_str = ast.literal_eval(s)
    dec_str = eval_str.decode('utf-8')
    fix_str = dec_str.strip().replace('\n', ' ')
    
    return fix_str

    
for e in extracted:
    print(fix_string(e))
```

Output:

```
i) SYRUP a
mi.
100
Te eT ran SYRUP
tamol, Ambroxol k
Guaiphenesin
Syrup
ol HCl &
quantity.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that assumes the substring you are looking for in each string is either between two newlines or at the beginning of a string and followed by a newline.

```
import re
def find_substring(string):

  string = (eval(string)).decode('UTF-8')

  pattern = r"\n?.*\.?\n" 
  lst = re.findall(pattern,string)
  if len(lst) == 1: 
    substring = lst[0].strip(".\n")
  else:
    pattern2 = r"\n.*\n"
    lst2 = re.findall(pattern2,"".join(lst))
    substring = lst2[0].strip("\n")
  return substring
```

Then, map to the list like so.

`list(map(find_substring,extracted))`

This outputs:

```
['SYRUP',
 'mi',
 '100',
 'SYRUP',
 'tamol, Ambroxol k',
 'Guaiphenesin',
 'Syrup',
 'ol HCl &',
 'quantity']
```